# Pytest parametrized fixture with pytest-lazy-fixture fails if moved to conftest

Tags: python, pytest

I've written this simple parametrized fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[
    pytest.lazy_fixture("client_a"),
    pytest.lazy_fixture("client_b"),
    pytest.lazy_fixture("client_c"),
])
def client_all(request):
    return request.param
```

It works flawlessly when put in a test file. When I move it to a conftest.py the result is:

> ImportError while loading conftest
> '/project/tests/conftest.py'.
> conftest.py:181: in 
> ??? E   AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'lazy_fixture'

Clearly debugging the plugin manager of pytest is unfeasible but I noticed the `pytest_configure` function inside `pytest-lazy-fixture` never gets called when I get this error but it does get called when the fixture works, so the problem must be when the list of plugins is loaded. I expect it to be some weird conflict with some other pytest option but I have no clue how to move forward from here.

Mind that the plugin is used in other files throughout the project but only to parametrize single tests and never as a fixture param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugins are configured after the conftest files and the fixtures have been loaded.

Hence, at the time your global fixtures are being registered the `pytest.lazy_fixture` namespace doesn't exist yet because the call to `pytest_configure` is yet to happen.

The correct way to use will be to load it from its own module itself:

```
from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture

@pytest.fixture(params=[
    lazy_fixture("client_a"),
    lazy_fixture("client_b"),
    lazy_fixture("client_c"),
])
def client_all(request):
   ...
```

[The docs don't clearly mention](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/writing_plugins.html#plugin-discovery-order-at-tool-startup) this, like when exactly the hooks are called, but in the source, we can see that happening in this order:

1. [`main()`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/b7603fa730666cfa86c128d5a0652829582cd930/src/_pytest/config/__init__.py#L133) is called
2. `main()` calls [`_prepareconfig`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/b7603fa730666cfa86c128d5a0652829582cd930/src/_pytest/config/__init__.py#L304). It loads and registers the plugins using the plugin manager(`PytestPluginManager`, a subclass of Pluggy's [`PluginManager`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pluggy/blob/389684c3378208ba7e62da0ee8cc21955288256d/src/pluggy/_manager.py#L53)).
3. [`config._do_configure()`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/b7603fa730666cfa86c128d5a0652829582cd930/src/_pytest/main.py#L264) then does the actual configuration by calling [`call_historic`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pluggy/blob/389684c3378208ba7e62da0ee8cc21955288256d/src/pluggy/_hooks.py#L267) in Pluggy's `_HookCaller` class.

Comment: woooow. I knew it could have been some tricky ordering thing and still I would have never thought this was among the possible answers. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's an [old issue](https://github.com/TvoroG/pytest-lazy-fixture/issues/16). [pytest_namespace](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-namespace) hook was removed in pytest 4.0, which means since `pytest.lazyfixture` is a plugin it's being added only after `conftest.py`. You can solve it by importing `lazy_fixture` directly

```
from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture

@pytest.fixture(params=[
    lazy_fixture("client_a"),
    lazy_fixture("client_b"),
    lazy_fixture("client_c"),
])
def client_all(request):
    return request.param
```